# Averaging a specific portion of a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, average

I am trying to compare two parts of a numpy array:

```
    a_matr = np.zeros([time_steps, 2], dtype=float)
```

I iteratively populate the first column with integers 0->1000 corresponding to time steps, and the second column with a population density at that time step.  After every completion of a given cycle of time steps length n, I would like to compare the average of the previous two cycles, i.e., the average of the range: a_matr[i-n*2,:] through a_matr[i-n,:], versus the average of the range a_matr[i-n,:] through a_matr[i,:].

Since n should be arbitrary, is there a way to select such ranges automatically, and pass it to np.average()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the two averages can be calculated like this:

```
a_matr[i-n*2 : i-n, :].mean()
a_matr[i-n : i, :].mean()
```

By the way, if you calculate the two averages in each iteration, you end up calculating each twice.  Instead, you can keep the previous average in a variable, and only calculate the newest one in each iteration.